# I want to convert my rvt file to svf format and keep it in my local

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

good day everyone. I need to view my rvt file in forge. I want to convert my rvt file to svf format and keep it in my local. Which API will I use exactly for this and the converted svf folder will be downloaded to my local?

Where can I get my user token for Authorization?

Is this the api I should use?

```
curl  -X POST  'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>'  -H 'x-ads-force: true'  -d '{
          "input": {
              "urn": "<BASE64_ENCODED_URN_OF_SOURCE_FILE>"
          },
          "output": {
              "destination": {
                  "region": "us"
              },
              "formats": [
                  {
                      "type": "svf2",
                      "views": [
                          "2d",
                          "3d"
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
      }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day to you,

You are looking forward to use the model derivative APIs, https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/overview/

So if you want the access token, you will have to go through 2legged Authentication
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v1/tutorials/get-2-legged-token/

As you know Forge is a cloud development platform , a set of web service APIs you can use to build innovative, cloud-powered applications. So the extraction of SVF in local system is not officially supported by Autodesk. You might want to go through this extractor at your own risk https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io , https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs